# Setting verbose name of function field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a simple Model like this:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Artist"
        verbose_name_plural = "Artists"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, blank=False)

    def test_function(self):
        return 'xyz'
```

And Admin:

```
class ArtistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'test_function']
    search_fields = ['name']
    readonly_fields = []
```

Now in the list view, the function field is verbosed as `TEST_FUNCTION`:

[image: list view in django admin]

In a normal field I would use the `Field.verbose_name` parameter.

How do I achieve that with the function field?

In object terms thinking, I would try to return a mocked `CharField` instead of a simple string. Would this work somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), you can give the function an attribute called `short_description`:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('upper_case_name',)

    def upper_case_name(self, obj):
        return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()
    upper_case_name.short_description = 'Name'
```

If set, the Django Admin will show this description rather than the function name. Even better, change it into `_('Name')` to allow for different translations!